# Is there Boost 1.5.3 package for Debian/Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, package, debian

Is there Boost 1.5.3 package for Debian/Ubuntu in a PPA someplace? The latest I find is 1.4.X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one [Boost 1.53](https://launchpad.net/~apokluda/+archive/boost1.53), you just need to specify the ubuntu version in ppa